# How do I change a folder to a jar?

Tags: macos, file-conversion

I play Minecraft like many gamers and I am trying to make a profile where I can read the enchanting table language and I cannot get it to work. How do I change the folder that I used to edit it into a jar?

Answer (score 9):

Compress the contents of the folder then rename the .zip to .jar

[image]

Answer (score 6):

From `terminal` use:

`jar -cvf filename.jar ./foldername`

`jar` works much the same as the unix archive command `tar`, the parameters `cvf` mean essentially *Create Verbosely Filename* which will just display the contents of `foldername` as they are added into `filename.jar`.

Instead of create you can use `x` for extract or `t` for test extract (aka list).

Answer (score 5):

Minecraft specifically will also recognize a `jar` without any compression at all—you can just rename your folder from (for example) `1.7.9 copy` to `1.7.9.jar`.
I find this really useful with Minecraft since I don't have to zip and unzip every time for it to work.